# Facebook invitable_friends API with user locale

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I use Unity3D to build WebGL game. And, now I'm trying to implement the invitable_friends API to show friend name.

I retrieved Friend's name in Unicode like "\u0e01f"(Thai character "ก") and "\u30b0"(Japanese character "グ") from Facebook Graph API.
In invite friend list, as I implemented my application with Japanese font, the "\u0e01f" character is not show.

So, I think about get the user's locale. Then, assign the correct font to show friends's name.

Do you have any ideas how to show user name with all language support?
or 
Is it possible to get user's locale or country for invitable_friends API?

Thank you in advance!!

PS. I already tried the following query, but it's not work at all...

```
me/invitable_friends?fields=country,locale,name,id,picture
```

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to retrieve the information.

Comment: @daviddoran thank you!! yeah , i think so. But, i hope there's a way that i can retrieve locale data from the user-node when using invitable_friends api...